# Incorrectly using prepareForReuse

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to set an object's hidden property based on the existence of a key in a dictionary in my cell's `prepareForReuse` method. I must be incorrectly using `prepareForReuse`. With the below code, it logs `"Key exists at ..."` when I scroll AWAY from the cell in which the object should be hidden. I expected it to log this as I was scrolling TOWARDS the cell. Nonetheless, my object is not being hidden.

```
-(void)prepareForReuse
{

NSDictionary *dictionary = [parseTrackArrayReference objectAtIndex:currentIndex];
if ([dictionary objectForKey: @"sliderEnabled"]) {
    playbackSlider.hidden = NO;
    NSLog(@"Key exists at index: %i", currentIndex);
}
else {
    playbackSlider.hidden = YES;
}
}
```

Comment: What sets the "`sliderEnabled`" object in your dictionary, and what is that object?  If it's not a "`NSNumber`" boolean, maybe it should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved method body to cellForRow and it works fine.